# laravel 4.2 pipe basd validation error

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-validation

getting error on when submit form

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Array to string conversion

below is the code that generate error  not validating the form

```
      $rulesvalida=array(
        'txt_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'txt_phone_number' => 'required|numeric|min:8',
        'txt_street_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'txt_house_number' => 'required|min:3',
        'txt_floor' => 'required|min:3',
        'txt_side' => 'required|min:3',
        'txt_post_code' => 'required|min:4',
        'txt_post_town' => 'required|min:4',
        'txt_country' => 'required',
    );

          return Validator::make($data, $rulesvalida, Lang::get('validation'));
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Perhaps the error is with `$data`?

Comment: array (size=8)
  'txt_name' => string 'dd' (length=2)
  'txt_phone_number' => string '34324' (length=5)
  'txt_street_name' => string '343' (length=3)
  'txt_house_number' => string '343' (length=3)
  'txt_floor' => string '43' (length=2)
  'txt_side' => string '' (length=0)
  'txt_post_code' => string '' (length=0)
  'txt_post_town' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: And what about if you remove the 3rd variable Lang() - does it still happen then?

Comment: yes then it will happen as well